How to setup Auto Layout constraints (or SwiftUI hack) that mimic iMessage's scroll-to-dismiss of input bar
Let's say I'm trying to mimic iMessage's message view. Currently, I have a UICollectionView and a text input view that are subviews of a UIViewController's view. The constraints are laid out to place the input view below the UICollectionView, like so:
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.topAnchor),
            
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            view.keyboardLayoutGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: textView.bottomAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            textView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 66)
            
        ])

View the whole gist here. This gist contains the sample code for the issue in both UIKit and SwiftUI.
I want the text view to follow the keyboard's top anchor as the user drags the collection view to dismiss the keyboard. That's the functionality in all first-party apps on iOS.
In my current constraint layout, the text view floats awkwardly at the keyboard's standard height as the keyboard gets dismissed interactively. The collection view expands to fill the gap below the text view, where the keyboard once was. The text view stays stationary.
If I change view.keyboardLayoutGuide... to textView.keyboardLayoutGuide..., I get the functionality I want, but UIKit whines about having to break constraints. Furthermore, initially, with that constraint change, the text view doesn't respect the bottom safe area. Here's the constraint breaking.
This same issue happens in SwiftUI. I would rather have this issue fixed in SwiftUI than UIKit – I would wrap my UICollectionView as a representable and stick my input view in a safe area inset – but I couldn't find a way to accomplish my desired functionality in SwiftUI. The second file in the gist is the SwiftUI code which has the same issue as described above in UIKit.
Here is a GIF demonstrating the problem. There's a GIF demonstrating what I am expecting on that same link if you scroll down. I used this article to find the keyboardLayoutGuide systemSpacing anchor.
